# Using xPath function in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Is it possible doing somthing like this `test/get[name()]` In iReport?

xml:

```
<test>
    <get>somthing<get>
<test>
```

So that I get "get" in the textField?

I want print out the name of a xml-tag or rather the element-name.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?